# Can I monitor the usage of individual directories with AWS CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch

I'm developing a platform where users will in effect have their own site within a directory of my own. Each user site will consist of a package of php scripts and the template/image files for their sites custom layout. Each user site will be connected to their own Amazon RDS. I need to be able to track the resource usage of each directory so that I can bill each user for the resources they have used. Would it be possible to setup custom metrics with CloudWatch so that I can calculate costs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use cloudwatch to do this, however, it might not be the most efficient place to put this information if you are going to bill or report on it. I think you are better off computing the data and then storing it in a database of your own. This way you have easy access to the data and you can do things with data that may not work well in the context of cloudwatch.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure how I would go about 'computing the data'. Could you point me in the right direction so I can research it.

Comment: It comes down to defining what resources you are going to bill for and how you can measure it. If you are billing on disk usage, you should be able to check the size of the user data on disk. For bandwidth, you are probably parsing log files generated by whatever webserver you are using.